# How can I handle dates of a 360-day calendar in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, calendar, python-datetime

So I have a Pandas Series object which is technically a list of dates from 2021-2040 with a one-day time step (daily dates). Apart from the time column I also have another column which contains daily maximum temperature values for the same time steps. I would like to somehow convert those dates to a datetime-type object so that I can do further calculations with specific date ranges. For example, tell Python to calculate the 3-consecutive days whithin the time range 1st April 2025 - 15th October 2025, when Tmax>30C. However, I cannot handle these dates because they are in a 360-day calendar format and therefore datetime module does not recognize them. How can I convert 360-day calendar dates to datetime-like object? Is there another package/module for this maybe? I have read the original Netcdf file and converted the time variable with num2date command, but I cannot further convert this into datetime object to perform calculations like timedelta etc.

### Thank you all in advance for any help!

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(path + excel_name)

## Extract the time series column and convert it to datetime format

time_series = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  # Assuming the date format is 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'

ValueError: time data "1986-02-29 12:00:00" at position 58 doesn't match format specified

Comment: Can you add more details? A 360 day calendar will have 30 days in each month. So you will have 30th February, and 29th February in a non-leap year, which does not exist in a standard calendar. This is causing the issue. You will need to explain what you want to do with those dates and the 5/6 missing dates in a standard 365/366 day calendar

Comment: What I ultimately want to do, is to find the index of specific time ranges, for example from 01/04/2021-15/10/2021 and then for these indices only find the occurrences of specific temperature thresholds from the same length temperature columns. 
time    max_T
date1    T1
date2    T2
...           Tn
where time is daily time steps drom 1/1/2021 - 31/12/2040 and T the maixmum daily temperature. I was thinking that in order to pick a specific time range I need to do it by converting my time series to datetime format. Maybe cftime will work by constructing my dates from string to 360-dates..

Comment: As I said, you need to clarify the question. Please do that in the question. It's not helpful to expand on the question in the comments. The question should be self-contained. As I said, you need to explain what you want done with the likes of the 30th February and missing dates in a standard calendar

Answer (score 0):

Handling dates in a 360-day calendar format in Python can be challenging because the datetime module in Python's standard library primarily deals with the Gregorian calendar. However, you can work with custom calendars using the cftime library, which is commonly used in the context of climate and weather data stored in NetCDF files. Here's how you can convert your 360-day calendar dates to datetime-like objects using the cftime library:

Install the cftime library if you haven't already. You can install it using pip:

```py
pip install cftime
```

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cftime

df = pd.read_excel(path + excel_name)
time_series = df['time']  # Assuming 'time' column contains your dates

calendar = '360_day'

cf_dates = [cftime.datetime(year, month, day, calendar=calendar) for year, month, day in time_series.str.split('-').apply(lambda x: x.astype(int).tolist())]

cf_dates_series = pd.Series(cf_dates)

# Assuming you have a column 'Tmax' containing temperature values
filtered_data = df[(cf_dates_series >= cftime.datetime(2025, 4, 1, calendar=calendar)) & (cf_dates_series <= cftime.datetime(2025, 10, 15, calendar=calendar)) & (df['Tmax'] > 30)]

# Now you can work with the filtered data
```

This code should allow you to work with your 360-day calendar dates and perform calculations based on specific date ranges and temperature values.

Comment: This looks like an AI-created response.

Comment: no, it's not @Dimitris